Proof that the theory of $\underline{Z}=(\mathbb{Z},s)$ has quantifier elimination.
I am pretty new to model theory so this may be a naive question, however I am having some trouble proving the following:
"Let $\underline{Z}=(\mathbb{Z},s)$, where $s$ is the successor function, and let $T=Th(\underline{Z})$. Then T has quantifier elimination (QE)".
What I was trying to do was to prove that each primitive formula is equivalent to a quantifier free formula. So, avoiding trivial cases where the formula is either always true or always false a primitive formula is of the form:
\begin{equation}
   \phi(y_1,\dots,y_k,z_1,\dots,z_l)=\exists x\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{k}s^{n_i}(x)=s^{m_i}(y_i) \wedge\bigwedge_{j=1}^{l}s^{\overline{n}_j}(x)\neq s^{\overline{m}_j}(z_j)\right)
\end{equation}
The truth of such formula in $\underline{Z}$ amounts to say that the following system admits solution solving for $x$:
\begin{equation}
\cases{
x+n_1=y_1+m_1 \\
x+n_2=y_2+m_2 \\
. \\
. \\
. \\
x+n_k = y_k+m_k \\
x+\overline{n_1}\neq z_1+\overline{m}_1 \\
. \\
.\\
.\\
x+\overline{n}_l\neq z_l+\overline{m}_l
}
\end{equation}
However from this point on I am kinda stuck. Is what I've done so far correct? How do I get past this point to get the proof? Are there any other more clever method?
Hope you guys can help me here :)

You are absolutely on the right path.
Start with the equalities. There exists such an $x$ iff $y_i+(m_i-n_i)=y_j+(m_j-n_j)$ for every $i,j$. This is not a first-order statement in the language, but luckily this is equivalent, after writing $N=\max\{n_i\}$, to $y_i+(m_i-n_i+N)=y_j+(m_j-n_j+N)$ for all $i,j$, and since all added elements here are nonnegative, this can be written with the successor symbol in first-order language. The part with the inequalities is essentially the same argument.
